# Undo action for Excel addin

Tags: c#, excel, interop, add-in

How does undo work in Interop.excel? C# - making a addin in VS

I imagine the following:

1. I register a undo-method on the stack (implemented by me).
2. I save the current state... where?

When the user uses undo (ctrl-z), my undo-method gets called, and I restore the previous state with the data that I stored.

Can't get any good info on this though. Maybe it works totally different?

Comment: Here's a VBA example: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/undoing_a_vba_subroutine/. I've never implemented Undo in VBA, but I believe the user is still limited to undoing just that last action.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at NetOffice http://netoffice.codeplex.com/ They are tutorials how to create your own Add-In. You can work with VSTO, download the NetOffice .dll which you need to write your own Excel Add-In and to design it as you wish and implement your functionalities.